# SIGCHLD causing EOF in parent process

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, fork

A minimalistic example of a program that

- reads char by char by getchar, until EOF
- starts a child process when an "a" is encountered.

Curiously, installing a signal handler causes `getchar` to return an EOF whenever a child exits. A rather unwanted side-effect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler() {
    // 
}

void action() {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("(action)\n");
        sleep(1);
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char c;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);                // signal
    while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {
        if (c == 'a') action();
    }
    printf("End Of Data\n");
}
```

The problem disappears when the signal ligne is commented out.
Can someone please explain why this happens?

Seems the same problem as [Handling SIGCHLD will return EOF to the father, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325711/handling-sigchld-will-return-eof-to-the-father-why)
which has no clear answer about why, and how to avoid this.

---

EDIT 1: Was not clear to me doesn't mean that much (friday evening...)

- The cause is, the system call under `getchar()` was interrupted, causing it to return `EOF` (as written in the manual page).
- (Ad hoc) Solution: check `errno` for `EINTR`.

On this example

```
 while (EOF != (c = getchar()) || errno == EINTR) {
```

---

EDIT 2: checking `errno` works with `getchar()`, but doesn't make you out of the woods with `getline()`.

The real solution is to forget about the obsolete `signal()`, and use `sigaction()` with the `SA_RESTART` flag.

Comment: Got it, after all. Interrupted system call. Check errno = EINTR.

Comment: @usr Sorry for silly qustion, it's friday.

Comment: You could use `sigaction` with the `SA_RESTART` flag to avoid the problem.

Comment: What libc and version is this? I thought glibc signal() abandoned this awful sysv behavior decades ago.

Comment: @R.. Debian squeeze distribution: 2.24.1. Compiler gcc version 6.3.0 20170516  with --std=c11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L.

Comment: @MichelBillaud: Uhg, looks like using one of the standard feature test macros without also `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE` (leading to `__USE_MISC` internally) causes `signal` to get redirected to the awful `__sysv_signal`... This should probably be treated as a bug in glibc and fixed. The standards **do not** require or recommend the broken sysv behavior, just allow it.

Comment: Anyway, were we expecting consistency when compiling a source with non-posix signals with -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L options...